# How to show tautologies in FOL using truth definitions?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Anyone know how to prove these tautologies by way of truth definition? I take it that to solve a), I need to disprove a minimal counter example to the formula/sentence given? If so, how to formally construct one? Do I consider the non given premises to be the empty set and is that even relevant? Otherwise, any other suggestions?
Well I thaught that one should create a model, in where I can show that the sentence is true. But my question is then how do I expand it so that it is true in all models?
I have also tried the approach where I use the fact that the null space _ {-phi} is true and phi is not under a model?

a) ⊨ ∀x∃y(x=y)
b) ⊨ ∃x(t=x), where t is a closed term

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by proving a tautology "by way of truth definition", but I'll take a guess. The completeness theorem for first order logic says that an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\phi$ can be deduced from an $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T$ if and only if it is true in all models of $T$ (here $\mathcal{L}$ is our language/signature). Taking $T$ to be the empty theory (in the language $\mathcal{L}$), we have that $\phi$ is a tautology (i.e. it can be deduced from no assumptions) if and only if it is true in all $\mathcal{L}$-structures (all $\mathcal{L}$-structures are models of the empty theory).

a) Let $M$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-structure. We want to show that $\forall x\, \exists y\, (x = y)$ is true in $M$. That is, for any $a$ in $M$, we need to find a $b\in M$ such that $a = b$. Easy: take $b$ to be $a$!

b) Let $M$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-structure, and let $t$ be a closed $\mathcal{L}$-term. We need to find $a\in M$ such that $t^M = a$. Easy: take $a$ to be $t^M$!

Comment: That looks good! I was unsure about how to formalize it. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Since it seems like you're new here, I'll point out that if you find an answer helpful, you can vote it up (by clicking on the up arrow to the left of the answer) and/or accept it (by clicking on the check mark below the up and down arrows).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I tried upvoting, but I am 4 reputation point shy ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your problem is about (first-order) *validity*, i.e. we want to show "by way of truth definition" that the following formulas :

> *a)* $\vDash \forall x \exists y (x = y)$

and

> *b)* $\vDash \exists x (t = x)$, where $t$ is a closed term

are valid, i.e. true in every interpretation.

In order to show that, "by way of truth definition", we need to apply the definition of *validity*, i.e.

> $\varphi$ is *valid* iff for every $\mathcal L$-structure $M$ and every *interpretation* $s: Var \rightarrow |M|$, $M$ satisfies $\varphi$ with $s$

and show that the above formulas have the desired property, i.e. we show that they are true for a "generic" $M$ and for all interpretations of the variables: in this way we conclude that they are *valid*.

So we must apply the construction of Alex's answer: take an $\mathcal L$-structure $M$ ("generic", i.e. we do not presuppose any specific "characteristic" about it) and show that (for e.g. the formula *a)*) for every $a \in M$ we can find a $b \in M$ such that $a = b$.

Our "choice" is possible for every interpretation in $M$ because with an interpretation we assign to $x$ a *denotation* (an object $a \in M$), and we are able, for every $a \in M$ that we may "choose" as denotation for $x$, to assign to $y$ a suitable *denotation* that satisfy the formula $x = y$; we can do this simply assigning to $y$ $a$ itself.

Being able to do this for every interpretation in $M$, we have showed that *a)* is *true in* $M$ (or we can say that $M$ ia a *model* of the formula) ; but $M$ is "generic", so our conclusion must be true for every $M$, and so we can conclude that *a)* is *valid*.

Comment: Thank you a lot!that clarifies the " for every M"  part!

Comment: I would upvote you, but I don't have enough rep.!